# how to download .csv file using API Endpoint in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, socrata, soda

I want to download a csv file from an API endpoint with pandas. I am using the following code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nu7n-tubp.csv').
```

However, the resulting dataframe has only 1,000 rows, even though the dataset is much larger (around 121k rows). How can I download all the rows?

I tried to specify a number larger than 1,000 with nrows but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socrata [typically requires you](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202949268-How-to-query-more-than-1000-rows-of-a-dataset) to page through data, which is set at 1,000 rows. You could modify it by increasing it by using the [`$limit` parameter](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/limit.html). [Based on the data set page](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Health/NYC-Dog-Licensing-Dataset/nu7n-tubp), this is about 122k rows, so can use a limit of 130k to get them all:

```
df=pd.read_csv('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nu7n-tubp.csv?$limit=130000')
```

You also may want to explore the [SodaPy](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy) library.